# footer stuck in middle of single post page wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

Here's my site in progress: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

Here's my problem: When you click on a post, it takes you to the single post page (like it should). However the footer's stuck in the middle of the page (when it should be placed at the bottom)!

Here's what i've tried:

changing the "min-height" attribute to "height" in the .single class (the class that defines how a single post looks)

&

moving the class attribute from the footer tag to it's parent div.

None of which have worked successfully!

My question: Is there a way to get the footer to behave like it should on the single posts page without compromising the footer style on the main page?

Thanks in advance everyone! I'm totally stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest fixing this with css. If you would like the footer to always be stuck to the bottom of the page, use **position: absolute;**, **bottom 0px;** If you would like to have the footer flow naturally, right below the content of the page, try using **float: left;**, **clear: none;**, **position: relative;**.

Comment: would you suggest adding this code to the .footer class (the class that's styling the footer)? if so, I tested your theory out with Firebug and it didn't work...thanks for your reply though! Also I'm not going for the "sticky footer" effect. I'm striving to get the footer to flow naturally below the page content like you mentioned.  Any other suggestions? Thanks again! :)

Comment: In order for the content of your page to flow naturally, you need to add **float: left;**, **clear: none;**, **position: relative;** to all the objects that would interact with the footer. Such as the header, middle section and YES, the footer. Like in here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQLtH/)

Comment: I took a quick look through your home page, seems you're using absolute positioning for everything. Try changing of your elements the way I suggested, above and you'll get the result you've wanted.

Comment: Thanks Boris! That did it! At first I thought I'd have to apply that to every element on my site! But i just had to add it on the #single id (that governs the way the single post looks) and the .footer class as well. Cheers!